# No video after Monterey update on 2019 Mac Pro

Tags: macos, video, mac-pro

I finally gave in to the update prompt on my 2019 Mac Pro. Now it boots but there is no video.  I can log into it from another computer and see that everything looks normal, including Finder running. I tried killing Finder and resetting the SMC but neither helped. Since it was fine before the update, it feels like a software issue.  I could make a bootable usb on a 16,1 iMac but I don't know if that would be useful.  Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Shine a torch [flashlight] on the screen & see if there's an image but no backlight.

Comment: No image.  The monitors power lights are orange - no video.

Comment: If the display is LCD, Tetsujin is making sure you check for backlight failure by closely inspecting for correct LCD function which requires a bright light source to determine.

Comment: Yes.  I did that.  I saw nothing and the power light on the display is orange indicating no video signal.

Answer (score 1):

Odds are this is not software, but here are steps to perform to isolate it.

1. shut down the computer and disconnect everything except for the display.
2. power on and watch for boot - if there is no screen visible before the OS loads, that’s making hardware more likely.
3. connect a keyboard and power down - hold option / alt to force startup manager to control the video and not the OS - https://support.apple.com/en-us/102603

If the screen works in step 2 or 3 then you have a software issue or accessory issue. Narrow down accessories you disconnected. If you have no luck, you’ll need to bring another OS to bear (or try recovery). If you get the video in startup manager, you can likely connect an external drive and recover an old OS on to the external drive to test your theory on the last OS.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-macos-recovery-on-an-intel-based-mac-mchl338cf9a8/mac

> **option-shift-command-r**: Start up from macOS Recovery over the internet. Use this key combination to reinstall the version of macOS that came with your Mac or the closest version that’s still available.

If you can't get to step 3 with a different display and different cable, you will need a repair where the Mac gets opened and test on minimum hardware needed to boot that Mac to troubleshoot what part(s) is/are failing.

Comment: Step 2, no video.  Step 3 seems to have stopped at startup manager as it does not respond to ping.

Comment: If I understand correctly, video at boot select is controlled by firmware, not the 580X but it still has to use the 580X to get data to the display.  Doesn't seem like both firmware and kexts could be borked so it sounds more like hardware?

Comment: I don't have a repair manual for the 2019 Mac Pro, but a graphic card is likely part of the minimal boot system. If you take out the card, try and boot and my guess is you get beeps. So the card has to be minimally functional to even pass POST and let the startup manager  (firmware) look for the boot sequence. The card firmware has everything needed for minimal display so Apple firmware is enough to get the basic screen to print for diagnostics and boot manager use. Fancy GPU features only come alive when the OS is loaded and proper drivers take over from firmware and talk to the hardware.

Comment: Sadly, you need a repair from step 2 - new cable, new GPU or some other thing internal to the Mac most likely, @critter43

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I called the local Apple store since I have a very expensive brick at the moment.  I was sent to apple support.  They had a hard time understanding I had a Mac Pro, not a MacBook, not an iMac.  Scary.

Comment: Don’t worry, thousands of calls for the other hardware get the front line in a rut sometimes,  you’ll get escalated fast to someone and the local store will surely help soon with triage. They have everything needed to isolate the issue fast, @critter43

Answer (score 1):

Odds are the software update is the problem and not the hardware.

Start Mac in safe mode

Starting up your Mac in safe mode can help you identify whether issues you’re experiencing are caused by software that loads as your Mac starts up.

You could also run the Apple Hardware test

https://support.apple.com/en-us/102550

Comment: Nice call on running ASD. I’m so used to the results being the same as trying a recovery / startup manager boot, I almost never go there but it could show something useful on intel based Mac Pro.

Comment: I don't know how to run hardware test without a display.

Comment: Use your "other" computer to see the result

Comment: The problem was very strange.  The Genius Bar thought the problem was the video MPX when neither HDMI port or USB-C on the IO card produced any video.  Then one of the USB-C ports on the top of the box produced video.  The HDMI ports would work if you used the USB-C port first.  So he reloaded the firmware, and the HDMI ports started working.  Apparently the 12.6.x to 12.7.1 update munged the firmware.